# Map vim commands to compile-time features

Tags: vim, vimrc

Vim has the notion of *features*, i.e. subsets of functionalities that may or may not be supported in an actual installation, based on compile-time flags. Presence of a feature can be checked with the `has()` function, and all the possible features can be enumerated with the `feature-list` command.

I want my vim script to be more robust by checking for features before using them. My problem is that it is not documented explicitly which command relies on which feature.

Specific example: some Linux distributions ship `vim.tiny` by default which is a heavily feature-restricted version of `vim`. If I launch `vim.tiny`, my `.vimrc` spits plenty of error messages. E.g. the `let` command is not available, but it is not obvious which feature provides this command. How could I reliably determine it? Or if it is not possible, how would I make my vim startup degrade gracefully for `vim.tiny`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting a Vim plugin for *vim-tiny* is difficult, as it consists of a **very** limited feature set. It's meant as a lean replacement of *vi*, supporting just a few mappings, nothing more.

That said, it is indeed possible to detect and assert certain capabilities, using `has()` and `exists()`. The errors on `:let` could be prevented by wrapping in `:if 1`, but as I said, better aim for a "normal"-featured Vim, and just add checks for availability of newer stuff (like *conceal*, persistent undo, introduced in Vim 7.3) and essential bugfixes (but only if you need them).

Comment: Ok the key info I missed was to use `exists()` instead of `has()` to check for commands, e.g. `if exists(':let')`